# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function after refresh view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem. In my project I show modal dialog with mvc view. When I show modal, and select table row and close modal its everythig OK. But when I filter view and close modal I have Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function in .modal('hide').

Where is problem?

Javascript

```
//Show modal dialog
function ShowParagraf(index) {
    selectedIndex = index;
    $("#ParagrafModal").modal('show');
}

//Close modal dialog
$("#saveParagraf").click(function () {
    var value;
    var table = document.getElementById("ParagrafTable");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
         if (row.classList.contains("selected")) {
             value = row.cells[0].innerText;
         }
    }
    $("#Paragraf" + selectedIndex).val(value);
    $("#ParagrafModal").modal('hide');
});

//Refresh (filter) view
function changeParagrafHandler(ish) {
    $.post('@Url.Action("ParagrafIndex", "FK")', { ParagrafString: ish }, function (result) {
        $('#ParagrafModal .modal-body').html('');
        $('#ParagrafModal .modal-body').html(result);
    });
}
```

Controller code

```
// GET: RejestrZamPubl
public ActionResult ParagrafIndex(string ParagrafString)
{
    if (ParagrafString == null) ParagrafString = "";
    List<ParagrafViewModel> _filteredList = FKRepository.GetParagrafList();

    _filteredList = _filteredList.Where(s => s.NUMER.StartsWith(ParagrafString)).ToList();

    return PartialView("ParagrafIndex", _filteredList);
}
```

Modal code

```
<!-- ParagrafModal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ParagrafModal" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    @*<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" style="margin-top: 25%">*@
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 90%">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Paragraf</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ParagrafString" name="ParagrafString">*@
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ParagrafString" name="ParagrafString" onkeyup="changeParagrafHandler(this.value);">
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="modal-body" id="ParagrafPartialView">
                @*<p>Modal body text goes here.</p>*@
                @Html.Action("ParagrafIndex", "FK")
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Anuluj</button>
                <button type="button" id="saveParagraf" class="btn btn-primary">Wybierz</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

View in modal

```
@model IEnumerable<Rejestry.Models.ParagrafViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ParagrafIndex";
}

<style>
    .tableFixHead {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

        .tableFixHead tbody {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            height: 600px;
        }

        .tableFixHead thead tr {
            display: block;
        }

        .tableFixHead th,
        .tableFixHead td {
            padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
            width: auto;
        }

        .tableFixHead th {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            background: #BBBBBB;
        }

        .tableFixHead td {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        .tableFixHead tr:hover {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }

        .tableFixHead tr.selected td {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
        }
</style>


<table class="tableFixHead" id="ParagrafTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NUMER)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAZWA)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAZWAPELNA)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="text_data">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NUMER)
            </td>
            <td class="text_data">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAZWA)
            </td>
            <td class="text_data">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAZWAPELNA)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.13.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".text_data").click(function () {

        $("#ParagrafTable tr.selected").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        })

        var tr = $(this).parent();
        if (tr.hasClass("selected")) {
            tr.removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            tr.addClass("selected");
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't re-include javascript in your Partial - you're reinitialising jquery, so any plugins are lost.

Comment: If you need initialisation code, then use event delegation, eg ` $(".text_data").click(function () {` -> `$("#ParagrafModal").on("click", ".text_data", function()` - and put this *once* outside your modal code.